# Can't find module Bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, gruntjs, browserify

The directory which i am running "grunt" on has node_module folder which contains all the modules including : Bootstrap, Browserify and others.

When i run "grunt"

I get :

```
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 12 files lint free.

Running "copy:build" (copy) task
Created 1 directories, copied 17 files

Running "concat:vendorcss" (concat) task
File "build-css/vendor.less" created.

Running "less:libremap" (less) task
File build/css/libremap.css created.

Running "jst:compile" (jst) task
File "build-jst/templates.js" created.

Running "browserify:vendor" (browserify) task
>> Bundled build/vendor/vendor.js

Running "browserify:libremap" (browserify) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'bootstrap' Use --force to continue.
```

It stops at browserify and says cannot find module 'bootstrap' before this scenario, it said there wasn't "jquery" which i installed with "npm install jquery" after restarting "grunt" , a few other missing modules were also reported subsequently which i installed.However with bootstrap, even after installing and making sure it exist in node_modules directory, i still have this error.

Any help will be appreciated.

> I am new to grunt, npm, nodejs etc. I am just trying to setup a
>   software.

**Task Code Appended.**

There are two Browserify tasks, i assume the first complete successfully from the output above ?

```
browserify: {
 vendor: {
        src: [],
        dest: 'build/vendor/vendor.js',
        options: {
          shim: {
            jquery: {
              path: 'bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js',
              exports: '$'
            },
            bootstrap: {
              path: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
              exports: 'bootstrap',
              depends: {
                'jquery': 'jQuery'
              }
            },
            leaflet: {
              path: 'vendor/leaflet/leaflet.js',
              exports: 'L'
            },
            'leaflet-markercluster': {
              path: 'vendor/leaflet.markercluster/leaflet.markercluster.js',
              exports: 'L',
              depends: {
                'leaflet': 'L'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

// browserify libremap.js -> bundle.js
      libremap: {
        dest: 'build/js/libremap.js',
        src: [ 'src/js/libremap.js' ],
        options: {
          debug: grunt.option('debug'),
          external: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'leaflet', 'leaflet-markercluster'],
          shim: {
            templates: {
              path: 'build-jst/templates.js',
              exports: 'JST',
              depends: {
                'underscore': '_'
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: show your browserify task in gruntfile.js please

Comment: @Shrike Please check the added code.

Comment: @Shrike any idea if its an issue of path ?
I just deleted both bower_componets and node_components and reinstalled. Then i noticed that, bower_components has the components required. When i run the script, it tells me that jquery is module is not found, meanwhile, it's at bower_components. If i go further to install it, it will be added to node_components and when grunt is run, it won't ask for it again and now, leaflet and so on but it somehow gets stuck at bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should help:

```
`bootstrap: {
          path: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          exports: 'bootstrap',
          depends: {
            'jquery': '$'
          }
        },`
```

The piont is you export `$` not `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
npm -g install bower
bower install bootstrap
```

Comment: ``root@student-mapper:/usr/local/src/libremap-webui# bower install bootstrap --allow-root
bower bootstrap#*               cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.0.2
bower bootstrap#*             validate 3.0.2 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower jquery#>= 1.9.0           cached git://github.com/components/jquery.git#2.0.3
bower jquery#>= 1.9.0         validate 2.0.3 against git://github.com/components/jquery.git#>= 1.9.0``

I did as you adviced but it did not solve the problem :(

Comment: Try this: `npm install bootstrap-browserify` and then run again

Comment: The bower_components directory has
''bootstrap  font-awesome  jquery  leaflet''
I tried now, and still same result.

Comment: I think it's a path issue from the grunt script ?
The first script of browserify is successful and the paths to bootstrap was written but the other doesn't have ? I can see just "external" with the names of components. Or that that mean different ?

Comment: can you post the Gruntfile (or part thereof)?